# Upgrading React-router-dom v6 multiple errors

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom, upgrade, react-ref

So I've been upgrading modules for a project that is not mine so I'm not familiar with the code, when I tried upgrading react-router-dom from 5.2.0   ❯  6.3.0 I stumbled with the way the routes are implemented.
Having replaced the reprecated modules I get multiple errors that basically say the routes are not being defined correctly but I tried everything and I can't get it to work.
These are the errors I get when I load the page.

```
Warning: Function components cannot be given refs. Attempts to access this ref will fail. Did you mean to use React.forwardRef()?

Matched leaf route at location "/" does not have an element. This means it will render an <Outlet /> with a null value by default resulting in an "empty" page.

Uncaught Error: [Navigate] is not a <Route> component. All component children of <Routes> must be a <Route> or <React.Fragment>
```

This is the app component that deals with the routes.

```
import routes from './App.routes'
import { lazy } from 'react'
import AppContainer from './containers/app'
import AuthContainer from './containers/auth'
import { Route, Routes, Navigate, useNavigate, useRoutes } from 'react-router-dom'
import { ModalError } from './components/ModalError/ModalError'
import { EnvironmentProvider } from './contexts/Environment'
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux'
import { hiddenError } from './store/slices/health'
import { FullScreenLoading } from './components/FullScreenLoading/FullScreenLoading'
import { Suspense, useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import * as actionsProfile from './store/slices/profile'
import { firebaseInit, getValuesRemoteConfig } from './service/firebase'
import { setSecret } from './service/cryptojs'
import axios from './config/axios'
import Maintenance from './pages/common/maintenance/maintenance'
import { googleAnalyticsRegisterView } from './components/GoogleAnalytics/GoogleAnalytics'

const App = () => {
  const [isLoadingConfig, setIsLoadingConfig] = useState(true)

  const [configBeSetted, setConfigBeSetted] = useState(false)

  const [appInitialized, setAppInitialized] = useState(false)

  const [configuration, setConfiguration] = useState({
    isMaintenanceWebMessage: null,
    isMaintenanceWeb: null,
    apiUrlRemote: null,
    timeoutRemote: null,
    secretRemote: null,
    publicWebUrl: null,
    publicTurnsUrl: null,
    successRedirectUri: null,
    errorRedirectUri: null,
    googlePlayUrl: null,
    appStoreUrl: null,
  })

  const token = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('tsu'))?.token

  const { showError } = useSelector((state) => state.health.health)

  const dispatch = useDispatch()

  useEffect(() => {
    firebaseInit(async (app) => {
      const config = await getValuesRemoteConfig(app)

      //Production
      axios.defaults.baseURL = config.apiUrlRemote
      axios.defaults.timeout = config.timeoutRemote
      setSecret(config.secretRemote)

      setConfiguration(config)

      setIsLoadingConfig(false)

      setConfigBeSetted(true)

      setAppInitialized(true)

      token && dispatch(actionsProfile.getProfileData())
    })
  }, [token])

  if (isLoadingConfig || !configBeSetted) return <FullScreenLoading />

  if (configBeSetted && configuration?.isMaintenanceWeb) {
    return (
      <EnvironmentProvider config={configuration}>
        <Maintenance message={configuration?.isMaintenanceWebMessage} />
      </EnvironmentProvider>
    )
  }
  return (
    <Suspense fallback={<FullScreenLoading />}>
      <EnvironmentProvider config={configuration}>
        {showError && <ModalError onClose={() => dispatch(hiddenError())} />}
        <Routes>
          {routes
            .map((route) => ({
              ...route,
              component: appInitialized
                ? googleAnalyticsRegisterView(route.component)
                : route.component,
            }))
            .map((route, i) => {
              const Container = route.private ? AppContainer : AuthContainer
              return (
                <Route
                  key={i}
                  path={route.path}
                  exact={route.exact}
                  render={(props) => {
                    return (
                      <Container key={i}>
                        <route.component {...props} />
                      </Container>
                    )
                  }}
                />
              )
            })}
          <Navigate to={token ? '/home' : '/'} />
        </Routes>
      </EnvironmentProvider>
    </Suspense>
  )
}

export default App
```

This is the routes component.

```
import { lazy } from 'react'
import { googleAnalyticsRegisterView } from './components/GoogleAnalytics/GoogleAnalytics'

const Home = lazy(() => import('./pages/app/home'))
const MyData = lazy(() => import('./pages/app/my-data'))
const ClientAttention = lazy(() => import('./pages/app/client-atention'))
const PhoneAssistance = lazy(() => import('./pages/app/phone-assitance'))
const InsuranceDetails = lazy(() => import('./pages/app/insurance-details'))
const FeePayment = lazy(() => import('./pages/app/fee-payment'))
const MyInsurance = lazy(() => import('./pages/app/my-insurance'))
const ReportClaim = lazy(() => import('./pages/app/report-claim'))
const Notifications = lazy(() => import('./pages/app/notifications'))
const Login = lazy(() => import('./pages/auth/login'))
const RecoverPassword = lazy(() => import('./pages/auth/recover-password'))
const Register = lazy(() => import('./pages/auth/register'))
const NewPassword = lazy(() => import('./pages/auth/new-password'))
const FrecuentlyQuestions = lazy(() =>
  import('./pages/app/frecuently-question')
)
const ProofOfPayment = lazy(() =>
  import('./pages/common/proof-of-payment/ProofOfPayment')
)
const SuccessPayment = lazy(() =>
  import('./pages/common/payments/success/SuccessPayment')
)
const ErrorPayment = lazy(() =>
  import('./pages/common/payments/error/ErrorPayment')
)
const AppRedirect = lazy(() => import('./pages/auth/app-redirect'))

export const privateRoutes = [
  '/home',
  '/my-data',
  '/phone-assistance',
  '/client-attention',
  '/details',
  '/fee-payment',
  '/my-insurances',
  '/report-claim',
  '/notifications',
  '/faqs',
]

export const publicRoutes = [
  '/',
  '/recover-password',
  '/new-password',
  '/register',
  '/certifacates',
  '/app-redirect',
]

const routes = [
  {
    component: SuccessPayment,
    path: '/success-payment',
    exact: true,
    private: !!localStorage.getItem('tsu'),
  },
  {
    component: ErrorPayment,
    path: '/error-payment',
    exact: true,
    private: !!localStorage.getItem('tsu'),
  },
  {
    component: Login,
    path: '/',
    exact: true,
    private: false,
  },
  {
    component: RecoverPassword,
    path: '/recover-password',
    exact: true,
    private: false,
  },
  {
    component: NewPassword,
    path: '/new-password',
    exact: true,
    private: false,
  },
  {
    component: Register,
    path: '/register',
    exact: true,
    private: false,
  },
  {
    component: Home,
    path: '/home',
    exact: true,
    private: true,
  },
  {
    component: MyData,
    path: '/my-data',
    exact: true,
    private: true,
  },
  {
    component: PhoneAssistance,
    path: '/phone-assistance',
    exact: true,
    private: true,
  },
  {
    component: ClientAttention,
    path: '/client-attention',
    exact: true,
    private: true,
  }
]

export default routes
```

And this is the main component where app is rendered

```
import React from 'react'
import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client'
import App from './App'
import GlobalStyles from './global-styles'
import ErrorBoundary from './components/ErrorBoundary/ErrorBoundary'
import store, { history } from './store'
import { HashRouter } from 'react-router-dom'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import * as Sentry from '@sentry/react'
import { BrowserTracing } from '@sentry/tracing'

Sentry.init({
  dsn: import.meta.env.VITE_SENTRY_KEY,
  integrations: [new BrowserTracing()],
  tracesSampleRate: 1.0,
})

const container = document.getElementById('root')
const root = createRoot(container) // createRoot(container!) if you use TypeScript
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <ErrorBoundary>
      <Provider store={store}>
        <HashRouter ref={history}>
          <GlobalStyles />
          <App />
        </HashRouter>
      </Provider>
    </ErrorBoundary>
  </React.StrictMode>
)
```

History is exported like export const history = createRef();

I know there is something about that ref property or HashRouter but in the documentation I can't find it.

Comment: Have you first gone through the v5 migration guide for all the breaking changes? https://reactrouter.com/en/main/upgrading/v5 It doesn't appear you've converted your code fully to RRDv6 APIs/code syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue 1

> Warning: Function components cannot be given refs. Attempts to access
> this ref will fail. Did you mean to use React.forwardRef()?

This does indeed appear to be related to the [`HashRouter`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/router-components/hash-router) component. You can look at the type declaration and see that the `HashRouter` doesn't consume a `ref` prop.

> ```
> declare function HashRouter(
>   props: HashRouterProps
> ): React.ReactElement;
>
> interface HashRouterProps {
>   basename?: string;
>   children?: React.ReactNode;
>   window?: Window;
> }
> ```

And also inspect the [source code](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/blob/main/packages/react-router-dom/index.tsx#L279-L302) to verify it also doesn't forward any React ref.

> ```
> /**
>  * A `<Router>` for use in web browsers. Stores the location in the hash
>  * portion of the URL so it is not sent to the server.
>  */
> export function HashRouter({ basename, children, window }: HashRouterProps) {
>   let historyRef = React.useRef<HashHistory>();
>   if (historyRef.current == null) {
>     historyRef.current = createHashHistory({ window, v5Compat: true });
>   }
>
>   let history = historyRef.current;
>   let [state, setState] = React.useState({
>     action: history.action,
>     location: history.location,
>   });
>
>   React.useLayoutEffect(() => history.listen(setState), [history]);
>
>   return (
>     <Router
>       basename={basename}
>       children={children}
>       location={state.location}
>       navigationType={state.action}
>       navigator={history}
>     />
>   );
> }
> ```

The `Hashrouter` instantiates and maintains it's own `history` reference internally. To fix the ref issue simply remove the ref.

```
const container = document.getElementById('root');
const root = createRoot(container);

root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <ErrorBoundary>
      <Provider store={store}>
        <HashRouter>
          <GlobalStyles />
          <App />
        </HashRouter>
      </Provider>
    </ErrorBoundary>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

If you have need to use a custom `hashHistory` object then use the [HistoryRouter](https://reactrouter.com/en/v6.3.0/api#unstable_historyrouter) and follow the instructions for rendering. Be sure to have `history@5` installed as a project dependency.

## Issue 2

> Matched leaf route at location "/" does not have an element. This
> means it will render an `<Outlet />` with a null value by default
> resulting in an "empty" page.

The `Route` component API changed significantly from v5 to v6. The `Route` components render all their content on a single `element` prop taking a `React.ReactNode`, a.k.a. JSX. `exact` is no longer used now that all routes are ***always*** exactly matched.

```
{routes
  .map((route, i) => {
    const Container = route.private ? AppContainer : AuthContainer;
    const Component = appInitialized
      ? googleAnalyticsRegisterView(route.component)
      : route.component;
    return (
      <Route
        key={i}
        path={route.path}
        element={(
          <Container key={i}>
            <Component />
          </Container>
        )}
      />
    )
  })
}
```

This also means there are no longer any route props. The routed components need to use the React hooks:

- `useNavigate` to access the `navigate` function that replaced `history`
- `useParams` to access path params that replaced `match.params`
- `useLocation` to access the `location` object

## Issue 3

> Uncaught Error: [Navigate] is not a `<Route>` component. All component
> children of `<Routes>` must be a `<Route>` or `<React.Fragment>`

Only `Route` or `React.Fragment` are valid children of the `Routes` component. If you want to redirect that `Navigate` component still needs to be rendered on a route. Specify the `replace` prop so the navigation action is a REPLACE instead of a PUSH.

```
<Route
  path="*"
  element={<Navigate to={token ? '/home' : '/'} replace />}
/>
```